# Problem with Drools Eclipse Workbench

Tags: eclipse, plugins, drools

When I attempt to go through the "New Drools Project" wizard in Eclipse (for Drools 5.0, Eclipse Helios), I reach a point where I receive the message, " No Drools Runtimes have been defined, configure workspace settings first"

I have the Drools binaries, but the problem I am having is that I do not know how to configure the workspace settings so that the binaries will be accessible in Eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to go into Eclipse Preferences and under the Drools option you can add runtimes.  Select "Configure Workspace Settings..."  You just have to add the folder where the drools jars are located.